# c#. Парсинг excel таблицы в json

Tags: c#, json, парсер, excel

[image: Занятие]

[image: Таблиц]

Реально ли и если реально, то как спарсить эту таблицу в json, в форматах:

```
{"rasps":[{"Day":num_day, "Group":group_num, "Less1":{ "first":{"name":name,"teach1":name,"teach2":name or null},"sec":{"name":name,"teach1":name,"teach2":name or null}}, "Less2"{},...},{...}]}

{"groups":[{"_id":group_num,"name":name, "kurs":num_kurs},{...}]}
```

Comment: нет четкой структуры

Comment: была бы четкая структура без пробелм  можно было бы

Comment: нада по группам(учебным группам) разбить данные  и сделать модель для них.

Comment: По-моему тут вполне более-менее нормальная структура. Повозиться нужно с парсингом многострочных данных, но вполне решаемо.

Comment: дело в том, что таблицу в excel, создается кем-то другим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет ничего невозможного. Чтобы облегчить вашу задачу, вам, скорее всего, придется воспользоваться такими библиотеками как :

- [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) (парсинг Excel таблиц)
- [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) (работа с json)

ну и конечно реализовать модель и логику ее валидации. Дерзайте! )